# Backing up and compressing Photos Library.photoslibrary

Tags: backup, photos.app

I am backing up `Photos Library.photoslibrary` using rsync.

In general my backup philosophy is to keep things only if they cannot be automatically regenerated. Can anyone recommend items inside this package which do NOT need to be backed up (thumbnails, etc.).

If you delete these items from a `Photos Library.photoslibrary` and then open in Photos.app, will those items be automatically regenerated? And is there documentation of such from Apple?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the thumbnails.

Comment: And how to regenerate them?

Comment: There is a support article on Apple about repairing the Photo Library. There is a regenerate thumbnails on that as well.

Comment: I see this option for iPhoto https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201769 but not Photos

Comment: I guess Photos combines it all into one Repair Option